# How can I find the final state of a jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a piece of code that does something like this -

```
$(selector1).hide(300);
...
...
...
if ($(selector2:visible).length==0)){
   $(selector3).show();
}
```

Here, `selector1` is a subset of `selector2`. The problem I have is that the last part of the code that is attempting to make `selector3` visible does not get past the `if` as `$(selector2:visible).length` is not zero. This is because `selector1` is still being animated. If I wait for 300ms for the animation to be completed, The code shall work fine. And I cannot use the completion callback functions - my code is too complicated for that. How do I get the `$(selector3).show()` to work under these circumstances?

My workaround was to use -

```
if (($(selector2:visible).length-($(selector2:animated).length)==0)){
   $(selector3).show();
}
```

But this seems like a code that is likely to break. I believe that, if I can make sure that the elements being animated are eventually going to be invisible, I can safely trigger `$(selector3).show();`. Is there a way to know the final states of a currently running animating element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use promises:

```
$(selector1).hide(300).promise().done(function(){
    $(selector3).show();
}
```

Comment: This is good to know, but I have multiple `$(selectorX).hide(300)` in a sequence of `if...else`. And my actual if statement is  `if (SomeVar==0 && ($(selector2:visible).length-($(selector2:animated).length)==0))` and `SomeVar` is calculated after the `.hide(300)` line. So placing the `SomeVar` calcaulation in each of the promise callback seems an overkill.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, do you have a sequence of animations or are they parallel?

Comment: It would look better parallel - See this http://bharath.lohray.com/site2/index.full.php#LBrag It is a list of brag points. You may apply brag filter on the top right corner. if you filter out everything, a <p> tag with a message appears. The problem is when the last set of points vanish and the p tag appearing. The same filter mechanism is used on other slides of the web page. So I cannot know of how many filters are checked and how many are clear :-( unless I try to save the state in some `data-state` custom attribute (should I do that?). This was overall too complicated to put up as a fiddle